# how to drop rows by slice?

Tags: python, pandas, slice

hey all i have this d_f

```
data={"col1":['2020-02-24','2020-02-24','2020-02-24','2020-03-24','2020-03-24','2020-04-24','2020-04-24','2020-05-24','2020-06-24','2020-07-24',],
"col2":[4,2,4,6,0,1,5,1,2,3],
"col3":[7,6,0,11,3,6,7,4,5,6],
"col4":[14,3,5,6,7,11,22,8,6,np.nan],
"col5":[0,5,7,3,8,2,4,6,2,9],
"type":["B","B","C","A","B","A","B",6,6,2],
"number":["one",np.nan,"two","one","one",6,2,5,"two",np.nan]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.set_index("col1",inplace=True)
df
```

i like to cut all the rows between the indexs 2020-02-24 to 2020-06-24
so i will have a data frame with only [2020-02-24,2020-06-24,2020-07-24]
in the index rows

I'm looking for something in the style of

```
df.loc[~"2020-02-24":"2020-06-24"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
df.loc[(df['col1'] >= "2020-02-24") | (df['col1'] <= "2020-06-24")]
```

Comment: I dont think there is a result column in the data

Comment: @sammywemmy - thanks for noticing. Corrected

Comment: i take your code and do that
df.loc[(df['col1'] <= "2020-02-24") | (df['col1'] >= "2020-06-24")]

Comment: this might not work if 'col1' is the index. unless the OP made a mistake in his question

Comment: I'm unable to run your example. I'm having keyerror

Comment: @AnyaPrecious you need to `reset_index` or not  run `df.set_index("col1",inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to gtomer for the direction

i use his code, and that code is solve it for me

```
df.loc[(df['col1'] <= "2020-02-24") | (df['col1'] >= "2020-06-24")]
```

Comment: why you posting an answer to yourself if its someone elses suggestion?

Comment: His answer gave me a good direction but was not correct.
He used "and" , while I used "or".
I also changed the direction of the big than and small than.

Anyway I gave him credit in my answer,
If this is not acceptable I will delete my answer